# non-variational formulation of imaginary time evolution

Tags: qiskit, experimental-realization, qiskit-runtime

I was wondering if there is a codebase online or if somebody here has implemented successfully the non-variational formulation of the imaginary-time evolution algorithm in qiskit. I know qiskit_algorithms have the variational formulation as VarQITE. But I am looking for the non-variational approach wherein each Trotter step of QITE is replaced by an evolution over a unitary operator as described in

https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/pdf/10.1103/PRXQuantum.3.010320

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41534-021-00409-y

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-019-0704-4